# Using roles in Spring:boot + Spring security. How do I control who can see what?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I currently have a functioning spring:boot web app where a user can log in and a user has a role. (Relationship functioning correctly). What I am struggling to understand is, how do then control who can do what? For example, how do I make it so that a certain webpage is only accessible by admins.

Here's an example, I only want admins to be able to access this 'match' page:

```
@GetMapping("/competition/{competitors}")
public String match(ModelMap map, @PathVariable(value = "competitors") String competitors, Principal principal) {

    String[] parts = competitors.split("-");
    String part1 = parts[0]; 
    String part2 = parts[1];

    map.addAttribute("part1", part1);
    map.addAttribute("part2", part2);
    return "match";
}
```

Match.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Match</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <p th:text="'Match of ' + ${part1} + ' and ' + ${part2}" />
</body>
</html>
```

My configure method:

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(
                        "/registration",
                        "/js/**",
                        "/css/**",
                        "/img/**",
                        "/webjars/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                        .permitAll()
            .and()
                .logout()
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .clearAuthentication(true)
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
            .permitAll();
}
```

Comment: if you configured SecurityConfig class you can do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42765947/4891892), configure by url path

Comment: Hello, I added my configure method. How would I add an admin-only URL to this?

Answer (score 0):

```
http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/competition/**").hasRole("Your role here")
```

anything under `/competition/**` has to have the role `Your role`

Added to your code snippet

```
http
     .authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers(
                 "/registration",
                 "/js/**",
                 "/css/**",
                 "/img/**",
                 "/webjars/**").permitAll()
         .anyRequest().authenticated()
     .and()
         .formLogin()
             .loginPage("/login")
                 .permitAll()
     .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/competition/**").hasRole("Your role here")
     .and()
         .logout()
             .invalidateHttpSession(true)
             .clearAuthentication(true)
             .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
             .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
     .permitAll();
```

Comment: I added your code and replaced "Your role here" with "admin". When I try to access this page now with a user that only has "ROLE_USER", it allows me access regardless.

Comment: can you try with `ROLE_admin`

Comment: I tried "ROLE_ADMIN"

Got this error: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: role should not start with 'ROLE_' since it is automatically inserted. Got 'ROLE_ADMIN'

Comment: what you have in `@RequestMapping("/resourcepath")` in controller

Comment: I have also tried hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"), which does not give me the error. However it still allows a user without the role admin yo access the page.

Comment: The controller? that is in my answer above. If thats not what you mean, can clarify what you mean by "@RequestMapping("/resourcepath")" ?

Comment: `@GetMapping("/competition/{competitors}")` is in a class file, generally its a Controller class, is there any annotation on top of the class `@RequestMapping`

Comment: For this controller class file, I have no @RequestMapping("/resourcepath")

The annotions are:

@Grab("thymeleaf-spring4")

@Controller
@SessionAttributes("name")